# What are qualified-id/name and unqualified-id/name?

Tags: c++

I was wondering if someone could explain there terms since I encounter them in many places. I know some basic theory about them but not sure what I know is right or wrong.

So can any one please explain these terms?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

A qualified name is one that has some sort of indication of where it belongs, e.g. a class specification, namespace specification, etc. An unqualified name is one that isn't qualified.

Read James McNellis' answer here:

[What is a nested name specifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103756/what-is-a-nested-name-specifier)

Given:

```
struct  A {
    struct B {
        void F();
    };
};
```

- `A` is an *unqualified-id*.
- `::A` is a *qualified-id* but has no *nested-name-specifier*.
- `A::B` is a *qualified-id* and `A::` is a *nested-name-specifier*.
- `::A::B` is a *qualified-id* and `A::` is a *nested-name-specifier*.
- `A::B::F` is a *qualified-id* and both `B::` and `A::B::` are *nested-name-specifiers*.
- `::A::B::F` is a *qualified-id* and both `B::` and `A::B::` are *nested-name-specifiers*.

---

Comment: What about `B` or `F`, are they unqualified, too? And `B::F`?

Comment: @oenone: Simple answer: if it contains `::` it is qualified

Comment: @David Rodríguez - dribeas: How does one state difference between: Qualified Id and Qualified name?

Comment: @Als: They are the same thing. The grammar only mentions *qualified-id* (there is no concept of *qualified-name* in the grammar), but the standard mentions *qualified name* a couple of times to refer to *qualified-id* in textual descriptions.

Comment: @David: But do see 1.6/2: "_X-name_ is a use of an identifier in a context that determines its meaning. (e.g., _class-name_, _typedefname_). _X-id_ is an identifier with no context-dependent meaning (e.g., _qualified-id_).`

Comment: Is the difference between `A::B` and `::A::B` that the first one is a qualified name, whereas the second one is a **fully** qualified name?

Answer (score 20):

A qualified name is one that specifies a scope.
Consider the following sample program, the references to `cout` and `endl` are qualified names:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()  
{
   std::cout<<"Hello world!"<<std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Notice that the use of `cout` and `endl` began with `std::`. These make them **Qualified names**.

If we brought cout and endl into scope by a using declaration or directive*(such as `using namespace std;`), and used just `cout` and `endl` just by themselves , they would have been **unqualified names**, because they would lack the `std::`.

Comment: so qualified name and qualified-d is same thing?

Comment: Basically think of it as if there is a scope resolution operator (the ::) then its qualified.

Comment: @x4d33746153706c306974: If you're not a compiler expert, you can reasonably ignore the difference. (Roughly speaking, a qualified-id is something that looks like it could be a name, e.g. `std::cout` before the compiler figures out that it's the name of the IOstream output object)