# Dictionary for vernacular of C++ language lawyers

Tags: c++, terminology, language-lawyer

In C++ there are terms that not mentioned or explained in most C++ books. For example:

- singular iterator ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441893/what-is-singular-and-non-singular-values-in-the-context-of-stl-iterators))
- qualified name ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7257563/what-are-qualified-id-name-and-unqualified-id-name))
- dependent name
- deduced context
- shadow
- x/gl/pr-value ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues))
- incomplete type ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/200xfxh6.aspx))

You won't understand compiler error messages if you don't know what they mean. 
I know meaning of all above terms (they are just example). Of cause after some not trivial googling - I could figure out term meaning.  In case of *singular iterator*, I had to look into gcc source code.

Is there a dictionary or something where these are explained and  defined in not too expert friendly way as in the standard?

Comment: I would say that if you have to know what these terms mean, you should be reading the spec, not a book.

Comment: AFAIK There is no detailed resource, besides the the standard. I'd suggest you split that up and ask those as single SO questions.

Comment: @ pmr I know what these terms mean (after some reseach).

Comment: I don't know what *singular iterator* means and I have been reading error messages for a long time...

Comment: @Rodrigo - from GCC error messages.  I do a lot of meta programming.

Comment: @David - my compiler (gcc48) will complain about singular iterator after seeing code like this:  list<int>::iterator it;  cout << *it;

Comment: No, unfortunately no such resource exists, the best you are going to get is the C++ standard. Probably second-best would be Stack Overflow, I have found quite a few questions related to terminology that have helped a lot (quick search): [What is singular and non-singular values in the context of STL iterators?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441893/what-is-singular-and-non-singular-values-in-the-context-of-stl-iterators) - I'm guessing "singular iterator" means "singular value" [What are qualified-id/name and unqualified-id/name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7257563/what-are-qualif

Comment: (To be honest, I know what *singular iterator* is from the standard, but had not ever seen it in an error message, and my guess is that you don't really need to know the precise meaning of these terms to understand the error messages)

Comment: @JesseGood:  You answered the question and then voted to close it as not a real question!?

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy: Somebody with access to moderator tools converted my answer to a comment. Because of that, I decided to close the question since I was being disallowed from answering the question. However, after reconsideration I voted to reopen since I do think it is valid.

Comment: @Jesse It is a valid question. However, I do wonder what the mods think the answer should be, if yours isn't good enough.

Comment: @Leonid, it might help to mention that gcc mentions singular iterators iff you define _GLIBCXX_DEBUG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, we have [the official C++11 final working draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf).

In this document, anybody may look up the phrases you mention:

- singular iterator  - <strike>not</strike> found, (24.2.1: "Iterators can also have singular values that are not associated with any sequence", and "An invalid iterator is an iterator that may be singular")
- qualified name - found, explained
- dependent name - found, explained
- deduced context - found, explained
- shadow - **not found**
- xvalue - <strike>not</strike> found, (3.10: An xvalue [an “eXpiring” value] also refers to an object)
- gl-value - <strike>not</strike> found, (3.10: A glvalue [“generalized” lvalue] is an lvalue or an xvalue)
- pr-value - <strike>not</strike> found, (3.10: A prvalue [“pure” rvalue] is an rvalue that is not an xvalue)
- incomplete type - found, explained

The remaining terms can be looked up in the internets but seem to be more or less vendor specific phrases, if I'm not completely mistaken.

---

**Updated** after Jonathan Wakely's comment.

Comment: See [iterator.requirements.general] for singular iterators. A singular iterator is an iterator with a singular value.

Try looking for xvalue not x-value etc.

Comment: "shadow" probably refers to "name hiding" which is in 3.3.10.