# expected primary-expression before ';' token and expected unqualified-id before '=' token

Tags: c++, class, compiler-errors

I've created two classes in c++
one called compte and the other bank

```cpp
class compte
{
    public:
        compte();
        compte(long,float);
        virtual ~compte();

        long Getnum() { return num; }
        void Setnum(long val) { num = val; }
        float Getsolde() { return solde; }
        void Setsolde(float val) { solde = val; }
        void deposerArgent(float);
        void retirerArgent(float);
        virtual void afficher ();
         protected:
        long num;
        float solde;
};
```

And the other is banque:

```cpp
class banque
{
    public:
        banque();
        virtual ~banque();
        string Getnom() { return nom; }
        void Setnom(string val) { nom = val; }
        string Getlieu() { return lieu; }
        void Setlieu(string val) { lieu = val; }
        list<compte*> Getcompte() { return compte; }
        void Setcompte(list<compte*> val) { compte = val; }
    protected:
    private:
        string nom;
        string lieu;
};
```

But I'm getting 2 errors in the following line of `banque` class
`list<compte*> Getcompte() { return compte; }`:

> ```
> expected primary-expression before ';' token
>
> expected unqualified-id before '=' token
> ```

Comment: How do objects of class `banque` know what `compte` is? Maybe you're missing a `compte* c` member?

Comment: @rturrado it's included

Comment: the problem that i'm using codeblocks and every time i make a class from File->new-> class i get this error. In other word, i dont write word by word I just enter the attributs

Comment: You only have `nom` and `lieu` members. Please include a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

Your methods  from`banque` have no access to any variable named `compte`. This is neither an attribute of your class, nor an argument, nor a global variable.

You can read the answer to this post to know what's an `unqualified-id`:

[What are qualified-id/name and unqualified-id/name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7257563/what-are-qualified-id-name-and-unqualified-id-name)

Actually, in the code you are showing, `compte` is a class name, not a variable. It means that `compte` represents a type (just like `std::string` or `int` would), not a value. Including it will only make the class **declaration** visible.

I'm only guessing here but what you need may be to add a `compte` attribute of type `compte` in your class `banque` (you might want to rename them to avoid confusion).